# CommitCheckinEventHandler TFS

Tags: c#, reporting-services, tfs

I am trying to automate versioning on SSRS reports.  This involves having a visible text string with a version number on it on each report.  I want to link this string to the TFS label and ensure that the string is updated with each check in.

We use TFS2010 as our source control. When a report is checked in I want to run an application to read the report, update the version number if it is the same as the previous version number and check in the new version again, if necessary, and label the report with the version number.

I can write a C# consol app that will check out the previous version of the report - get the version number from our arbitrary place for it, compare it to the latest checked in version and update and check it in again with an appropriate label.

What I can't work out how to do is to fire this script off. (and where it will be hosted).  I am aware of the TFS CommitCheckinEventHandler but can't see how to register for it - has anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating a TFS Build that fires on each Check-In (Continuous Integration Build).  From the build you can call your console app, or run any other custom code you desire.

Comment: That's an interesting idea; I was thinking I might have to use a windows service which seemed an overkill!

Comment: You can use the TfsVersion activity from the Community TFS Build Tools to get the version number from the build number. You can then update the XML output during the build and your build drop will contain the versioned output. You then never need to update the checked in code and indeed you should set the version to something (0.0.0.0) to help you identify when a developer has deployed from their local computer rather than versioned output.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must learn to develop on Workflow Foundation, and so develop your specific activity, secondly create specific processus template based on sequential workflow, and you finish by adding your activity in your template process (Your workflow).
It's best practise

Comment: I'm sorry - but I don't really understand how this helps. When someone checks in a report I want to read it, possibly change it and save it.  I can do all of those things except I don't know how to trigger the process off.  Could you be more specific as to how to do that?

Comment: Hi Simon, your code must be encapsulated in activity of your workflow